# youtube api iframe loadvideobyid starts video where last one left off

Tags: iframe, youtube-api

I am using youtube api iframe and just getting going with the sample code.  When I issue:
player.loadVideoById("ytidNo1") the proper video starts ("ytidNo1" is a valid youtube id)

Then, say, 10 seconds later, if I issue another:
player.loadVideoById("ytidNo2") the 2nd video starts, but it starts at the point where the last one was playing at (eg 10 seconds in).

This is new behavior in the last day or so and I have not changed my code.

To correct the problem, I tried:
player.loadVideoById("ytidNo1",0)

then

player.loadVideoById("ytidNo2",0)

and issue still happens.

Anyone else have or just starting to have this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same problem.  Playing around I eventually got it to work.
I had to use seekTo(0); (see Jim's comments)

More details about the problem.

- If the video actually played to the end I didn't need to do anything.
- If the video was skipped part way through I had to call 
  player.seekTo(0); 
  on the old video before calling loadVideoByID("ytid", 0); on the next video.
- I also had to handle the case where after calling loadVideoByID I got an error. (e.g. 150)  If I had an error I could not call seekTo because it would cause the next video to play audio only.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to reproduce the issue using the official sample::

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

after the stop I am selecting another video in the same way, and seems to work well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
        player.loadVideoById("tYrND5hMY3A");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5wxFv/3/

Comment: Thank you. I tried your link and the issue appears to be Safari browser on iPad ... the exact behavior that I described occurs on the Safari browser on iPad, but eg not on Chrome on PC.

Comment: Fixed the problem by using the following sequence:
player.stopVideo();
player.loadVideoById("ytid",0);
player.seekTo(0);