# YouTube API 2017 loadVideoById() with startSeconds:0 always starts where I left off

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have the same problem as these people and tried all the solutions:
[YouTube API loadVideoById startSeconds not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239518/youtube-api-loadvideobyid-startseconds-not-working)
[Youtube IFrame Player API - Disable Youtube auto resume video where I left off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279527/youtube-iframe-player-api-disable-youtube-auto-resume-video-where-i-left-off)
[youtube api iframe loadvideobyid starts video where last one left off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777534/youtube-api-iframe-loadvideobyid-starts-video-where-last-one-left-off)

Supposedly it was a Youtube bug that was fixed almost 3 years ago but it's still not working for me. I tried loading the video in multiple ways:

1-Normal function call:

```
player.loadVideoById(container.data('youtube_id'), 0, 'hd1080');
```

2-Object function call:

```
player.loadVideoById({
    videoId: container.data('youtube_id'),
    startSeconds: 0,
    suggestedQuality: 'hd1080'
});
```

3-cueVideoById() then seekTo() (suggested on a blog):

```
player.cueVideoById(container.data('youtube_id'), 0, 'hd1080');
player.seekTo(0);
```

4-Stop the video, load the new one, seek to 0 (From another StackOverflow answer):

```
player.stopVideo();
player.loadVideoById(container.data('youtube_id'), 0, 'hd1080');
player.seekTo(0);
```

Whatever the approach, the startSeconds parameter from [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Queueing_Functions) is completely ignored and the video resumes from the last point.

However.. while in the browser, if I open the JavaScript console and type `player.seekTo(0)`, then it's working. This is very frustrating, using Youtube's exact instructions and still being unable to do what it's supposed to.

**NOTE**:
I could use onPlayerStateChange() after loading the video, then seek to 0 manually after it's loaded, but it just seems stupid and annoying to have to do it myself when the YouTube API is supposed to do it. So I would really like to fix this issue the correct way.

Comment: Can confirm. Same happening to me even after refreshing.

Comment: this problem just started occurring in my app too